# Gitlab SSH connection timesout on recursive commands

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have a gitlab repo which contains several submodules (max depth 3). the problem is each time I run a remote git command with multiple requests ex, `git submodule update --recursive --remote` it does two or three operations then times out on the rest with the message in the image.

I tried different machines and ssh keys but no difference.
[image]